# JQuery FullPage.js make text not be in the centre

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, fullpage.js

As in the title.  Is it by default centred?  I read through the jquery.FullPage.css file and I can't find a way to make the text be anywhere in the page except from the centre, centre-left, or centre-rigth.

Cheers

Comment: You can add or overwrite a CSS to the that element to make it what you want.

Comment: Can you show me? I don't know what is that element to overwrite it

Answer (score 0):

By default it is vertically centered as detailed in the documentation. The option `verticalCentered` is by default set to `true`.

Regarding the horizontal centering, you should be using your own CSS for that as you can see in any of the available [demos online](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) and the ones provided in the docs.

Comment: Hello Alvaro, I discovered that after I asked, how can I have verticalCentered to true in some sections and in some others to false? i dont have any knowledge of jQuery or Javascript if this is a dull qustion I apologise

Comment: Just overwrite it with your own CSS. `#section1 .fp-tableCell { display: block; }` to disable it.